# SVG shows tiny in IE10/11

Tags: html, css, svg

Not sure why. Used SVG for interactivity on this module. IE10&11 shows tiny.

Here's IE11

[image]

Here's Chrome

[image]

Stipped down example https://jsfiddle.net/hLy65yx4/

*SVG code too long for SO*

```css
.map{margin:2.75rem 0 1rem;position:relative}svg g.state polygon,svg g.state path{fill:#e0e0e0;stroke:#fff;stroke-miterlimit:10;pointer:default}svg g.active.state polygon,svg g.active.state path{fill:#c1c1c1;cursor:pointer}svg g.name path{fill:#fff;cursor:default}svg g.highlight.name path{fill:#c1c1c1;cursor:default}svg g.active.state .hover,svg g.active.state .path,svg g.highlight.name .hover{fill:#ff6b0b}.state .info{display:block;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;color:#000;z-index:10;padding:10px;width:300px;background:#fff;box-shadow:0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(50,50,50,0.75)}.state .info h3{font-size:14px}.map .info{max-width:200px;background:#fff;color:#000;padding:20px;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;z-index:10;font-size:14px;box-shadow:0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(50,50,50,0.4)}.map .info .arrow{position:absolute;z-index:10;cursor:pointer;color:#fff}.map .info .arrow.up{left:90px;top:-28px}.map .info .arrow.left{left:-13px;top:5px}.map .info .arrow.right{right:-13px;top:5px}.map .info .arrow.down{left:90px;bottom:-26px}.map .info .close{position:absolute;right:10px;top:10px;z-index:10;cursor:pointer;color:#c1c1c1}.map .info h2{color:#ff6b0b;font-size:17px;border-bottom:solid 1px #c1c1c1;padding-bottom:5px}.map .info h2 a{color:#ff6b0b;-webkit-transition:color 0.3s;transition:color 0.3s}.map .info h2 a:hover{color:#be4b00}.map .info ul{list-style-type:none;margin:0;padding:0}.map .info ul li{width:100%;display:block;float:left}.map .info ul li a{color:#000;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline}.map .info ul li a:hover{text-decoration:none}@media screen and (min-width: 0em) and (max-width: 31.9375em){.map .info{left:25% !important;top:50px !important}.map .info .arrow{display:none}}@media screen and (min-width: 32em){.map .info.arizona{left:250px;top:375px}.map .info.california{left:125px;top:375px}.map .info.colorado{left:400px;top:275px}.map .info.connecticut{left:745px;top:165px}.map .info.delaware{left:710px;top:235px}.map .info.guam{left:225px;top:555px}.map .info.hawaii{left:80px;top:555px}.map .info.louisiana{left:650px;top:505px}.map .info.missouri{left:640px;top:315px}.map .info.new-mexico{left:375px;top:400px}.map .info.indiana{left:740px;top:275px}.map .info.massachusetts{left:740px;top:145px}.map .info.maryland{left:640px;top:240px}.map .info.nevada{left:175px;top:275px}.map .info.new-jersey{left:715px;top:190px}.map .info.new-york{left:670px;top:150px}.map .info.oregon{left:125px;top:125px}.map .info.pennsylvania{left:625px;top:205px}.map .info.puerto-rico{left:645px;top:545px}.map .info.saipan{left:855px;top:545px}.map .info.texas{left:525px;top:475px}.map .info.virgin-islands{left:450px;top:580px}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... defining the width seems to have fixed this `width="1100" height="861"`